# Prevent Diagonal movements

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm developing a 3D tactical RPG game and I would like to know how I could prevent diagonal movements when the NPC moves? I want him to detect where the human player is in the grid and then go after him.

I can take their grid position but it didn't work. The NPC makes diagonal movements and starts to "sink" in the grid.I've tried something like this, target position is a vector 3 and I call the function in Update(), this script is attached to the NPC:

```
public void MoveNPC()
    {
        HumanPlayer = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player");
        ScriptPlayer PlayerPosition = HumanPlayer.GetComponent<ScriptPlayer>();
        NPC NPCPosition  = this.GetComponent<NPC>();


        if ((PlayerPosition.GridPosition.x - NPCPosition.GridPositonNPC.x) + PlayerPosition.GridPosition.y - NPCPosition.GridPositonNPC.y) >= movMax &&
            (PlayerPosition.GridPosition.x -NPCPosition.GridPositonNPC.x) + (PlayerPosition.GridPosition.y - NPCPosition.GridPositonNPC.y) <= movMax)
        {
            if((PlayerPosition.GridPosition.x - NPCPosition.GridPositonNPC.x) - (PlayerPosition.GridPosition.y - NPCPosition.GridPositonNPC.y) >= movMax &&
            (PlayerPosition.GridPosition.x - NPCPosition.GridPositonNPC.x) - (PlayerPosition.GridPosition.y - NPCPosition.GridPositonNPC.y) <= movMax){

                targetPosition = HumanPlayer.transform.position;
                targetPosition.y = 1.4f;
            }
        }

        if(this.transform.position != targetPosition)
        {
            this.transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, targetPosition, velocity * Time.deltaTime);
        }
    }
```

How could I solve it?

Comment: For 1 you are using `MoveTowards` which does exactly what you are seeing.  You need to create your own movement which is really simple.  Just a 4 if-conditional check.  `If (position.x < target.x) position.x++; else if (position.y < target.y) position.y++`  You get the idea.

Comment: So, would it be something like this?                                                 ```if(this.transform.position != targetPosition)
        {
            if (this.transform.position.x < targetPosition.x)
            {
                this.transform.position.x++;
            }

            else if(this.transform.position.y < targetPosition.y)
            {
                this.transform.position.y++;
            }                                                                                                                             ```

Comment: Yeah, almost sure it would work.  But don't forget the `>` cases.  You'll have to decrement x and y also.

Comment: Yes,  but when I type this line ```this.transform.position.x++;``` I get this error message: "Cannot modify the return value of Transform.position because it is not a variable". So, I have to create a variable like ```newPlayer x = this.transform.position.x++;```

Comment: My apologies. position.(xyz) are read-only.  You'll need to do `transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x+1, transform.position.y, transform.position.z)`

Comment: @jiveturkey no problem. I think now I'm able to solve it. Thanks for helping!